# Time Trigger - Bulk process handling

Tags: apex, scheduled-apex, time-dependent-workflow

I have a time based trigger (action on PB) which when met updates xyz field of account on last day of month. Suppose there were 300 records which initiated this time based Trigger on different occasions during Aug month. Now I have 300 records ready to be updated on 31st August.

Question : Will these 300 records be updated in one go (same context) or in different contexts independent of each other( 300 threads or context of 1 record each) ?

Thank you in advance

Comment: see https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/107891/how-are-records-batched-from-time-based-workflow-updates

Comment: Thanks for your quick response however the link not mentions clearly whether the time triggers collected on hourly basis run in one context or in separate contexts. For them static variable count is coming out to be 1000 which indirectly means all time triggers on hourly basis run in one context however not sure because the discussion move more towards state of static variables in batch processes. I will try debugging it in my test org. Thank you again for sharing the same.

Comment: From the article you can infer they run as a batch